# NPM Install - unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, npm, anaconda

I am simply trying to install NPM on my Mac (running Mojave), I am getting this same error message whenever I attempt an NPM command.

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro:~ jt$ npm install

/Users/jt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I run into the same problem with any npm command (i.e.)

```
/Users/jt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: What version of node and npm do You use?

Comment: as @KrzysztofGrzybek mentioned do a `npm -v ; node -v` and post the version numbers. also `npm` seems to be already installed (you can check where with `which npm`)

Comment: I do believe that npm may be installed, the problem is that I am getting the same error with any npm command. ~ jt$ npm -v

/Users/jt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Comment: You still haven't told us which version of node you are running. I'd guess a very old one that doesn't understand `let`. Upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I think it was a problem with my anaconda package. I was able to resolve it by reinstalling.